# Efficiency question : Is it better to concatenate code into a single file or to make local modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I work with module-like objects for a js game i'm making, like `time`, `player`, etc, all separated in single .js files that i then concatenate with gulp into a single big uglified .js file loaded into the header of my app (built with electron).

My question is : Is it not efficient ? Should i make each of these files individual local modules that i call like `const time = require("./time.js")` ?

Comment: modules should be separated with respect to functionality

Comment: Modular programming it is!!

Comment: It should not matter a lot, maybe affect startup performance a little. Test it.

Comment: When it comes to performance, it's usually a good idea to measure before, during, and after your changes.  Often, attempts to make something faster either don't actually make it faster, or do that in addition to making it more complex, and more difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your code is being transpiled and not interpreted as it is. There is no/low performance impact about using one file or fifteen. The tool you use to wrap your code will optimize it.

The most proper way to deal with a project is to separate the different functionalities into separated files.

Use functions, classes and modules to structure the code and makes it easier to understand, easier to maintain and easier to evolve.

When you are looking for the **player** code, it's easier to look for the file **Player.js** than using a **ctrl+shift+f** on all the project.

It's also easier when working as a team. It can avoid tons of merge conflicts.

[image]